# Javascript form validation on next button i have same class for all button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in JavaScript, and need some help with form validation.

I've got a form with 3 buttons, named as next, previous and at the end submit these button have same class name btn, when I put the function on next button with class btn it applied on all, and I fail to change class or add any ID because this is in JavaScript.

Can any one can tell how to handle by btn class but only apply on next button?

my code is

```
<form class="ms-form">
    <input type="text">
    <button class="btn">prev</button>
    <button class="btn">next</button>
    <button class="btn">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(.btn).click(function() {
        alert('ok');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you show, What you have tried?

Comment: Can you inspect and show us the button html code?

Comment: <form class="ms-form"><input type="text"><button class="btn">prev</button><button class="btn">next</button><button class="btn">submit</button></form> <script>$(.btn).click(function(){alert('ok');});</script>

Comment: @Alex, post this code on your question, and also the buttons code. We can help to format it after you posted it there

Comment: there should be something different in these 3 button, maybe  type = submit, maybe name is different.
find out the difference and use that.

Comment: Plesae modify the Question and show the three button html code.

Comment: `$('.btn').eq(0).click()` Will apply on the first btn found... Not classy but works. I'd really suggest you add a second class in your HTML, or an Id, or name... Could also loop through the .btn and test on their innerHTML but that is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jQuery selectors brother,

```
    $('.btn:eq(0)').click(function() {
       // click handler for prev
    });

    $('.btn:eq(1)').click(function() {
       // click handler for next
    });

    $('.btn:eq(2)').click(function() {
       // click handler for submit
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes around the class like  `$('.btn').click(function() {`

To just apply to the next button (and without adding a new class or adding ID) you can do:

```
$('.btn').eq(0).click(function() {
    alert('this is the PREV');
});
$('.btn').eq(1).click(function() {
    alert('this is the NEXT');
});
$('.btn').eq(2).click(function() {
    alert('this is the SUBMIT');
});
```

Fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/4axKE/2/)**

Or you can use something like:

```
var next;
$('.btn').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == 'next') {
        next = this;
    }
});
$(next).click(function () {
    alert('ok');
});
```

**The best way to this** this though is by adding a new class or id to the buttons.

Comment: sir i want alert only on next please

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 way

Write the onclick function and call the function inline itself as

```
<button class="btn" onclick="alertme();">submit</button></form> 
<script>
function alertme() {
   alert('ok');
}
</script>
```

OR Else

set another class name for the button

```
<button class="btn clickme" >submit</button></form> 
<script>
 $('.clickme').click(function() {
     alert('adad');
 );
</script>
```

---

**EDIT**

I don't know this is the right way of doing it. Just try this

Set values to the button as

```
  <button class="btn" value="prev">prev</button>
  <button class="btn" value="next">next</button>
  <button class="btn" value="submit">submit</button>
```

In javascript

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr("value") == 'next') {
     alert("next code here");
  }
});
```

Comment: it is dynamic class if i add clickme it added in all

Comment: can set dynamic values to the buttons ? <button class="btn" value="next">next</button>

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script to be the following:

```
$('.btn:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
    alert('ok');
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FdfbE/)

Pay attention to 2 things:

1. You didn't have parentheses in your jQuery selector
2. This will work as long as your "Next" button is always the second `btn` child of the `form`

For a more correct solution, I would suggest adding a unique class (or ID) to the "Next" button and use it to apply Event Listeners.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are dealing with dynamically added buttons, you could go for.

```
$(function(){

$("body").on('click', '.btn',function(){ // Handle click by propagation

var v = $(this).val();//get the Value

if(-1!=v.indexOf('ev')){

console.log('prev') // or alert('prev')
}


if(-1!=v.indexOf('xt')){

console.log('Next') // or alert('Next')
}


if(-1!=v.indexOf('mit')){

console.log('Sumbmit') // or alert('Submit')
}
})                       
})
```

Hope this helps someone.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74UUr/